# Show $f'(0)$ exists and is $L$

Tags: limits, derivatives

Our assumptions for this problem are:

$f$ is continuous on an interval containing $0$ and differentiable for all $x$ not $0$. Moreover, $$\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = L.$$

We must show that $f'(0)$ exists and is $L$.

My thoughts so far:
I am able to produce a (somewhat drawn out) argument for the case in which $f'$ is differentiable at $0$ but cannot seem to account for when that is not necessarily the case. Any help in reducing this argument to that end is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'Hopital's rule applies here quite nicely. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=f(0)$, so $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(h)}{1}=L.$$

Comment: This proof is correct, but a bit circular. How do you prove L'Hopital's rule (even in this simple case) when you DON'T know beforehand that $f$ is differentiable at $0$? ANSWER: by using the mean value theorem, of course. So it is probably better to use the MVT directly in this case. Anyway, for school the l'Hopital proof very likely suffices.

Comment: I never assumed that $f$ is differentiable at zero. We use the fact that it is differentiable near zero show that the limit which defines the derivative near zero exists, and is equal to $L$. L'Hopital's rule requires that the numerator and denominator be differentiable at every point in a neighborhood of $0$, but not at $0$ itself.

Comment: That's not my point. My point is, yes, l'Hopital's rule holds even without knowing beforehand that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and the derivative equals $L$ - but how is THAT proven? In some parts of the world, this most general form of l'Hopital's rule is proved only in graduate courses; in other parts of the world, in high school. And the proof uses the MVT (or, in the general case, Cauchy's mean value theorem). By comparison, it is pretty trivial to prove l'Hopital's rule when you know beforehand the function(s) is/are continuously differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a L'Hopital argument, but I don't want to worry about the hypotheses.

Fix $x > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$, the mean theorem theorem asserts the existence of $c_x \in (0,x)$ such that
$$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = f'(c_x).$$
Thus
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{x \to 0} f'(c_x) = L$$
since $c_x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Repeat for $x < 0$ for the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You must show $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac {f(x) - f(0)} {x - 0}$ exists and equals $L$. Use Lagrange's mean value theorem for $f$ on the interval $[0, x]$ (if $x$ is positive, or $[x,0]$ if $x$ is negative). Then use the fact that $f'(\xi)$ has limit $L$ if $\xi \to 0$ with $\xi \not = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am self-studying Abbott's understanding analysis 2 ed. This problem appears as exercise 5.3.8. I found an alternative proof, and I would appreciate it if you comment on it.

Let $l(x) = f(x)-f(0)$ and $g(x) = x$. By the Generalized Mean Value theorem, there exists a point $c \in (0,x)$ (the case with $x<0$ can be derived analogously) so that $\frac{l'(c)}{g'(c)}=l'(c)=f'(c)=\frac{l(x)-l(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$.

Taking limits as $x \rightarrow 0$ on both sides of the inequality, and recalling that $0<c<x$ gives us $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f'(x)=L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$, the right side of the inequality being precisely the definition of the derivative of $f$ at zero, proving the desired result.